# Inserting links in the Pages document

Tags: pages

Here is a nuisance that I'm encountering during my word processing using Apple Pages. Every time when I need to make an external link (http link) to some web page I need to make sure to edit the link field from http://livepage.apple.com/ to my desired one. Now this is not a problem if you need to do this procedure once or twice but you can imagine how frustrating this can get with more links.

I wonder if there is a preference to change this into say the one from the clipboard?

Any other suggestions on how to proceed in this case would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when you paste a link or write it out, you just need to go on typing and Pages automatically converts it to clickable text.